# How are the "cartoon" images made and what is their "proper" name?

Tags: image-processing

How are the "cartoon" images made and what is their "proper" name?

1. How do people create these cartoon-style images? One option I found is BioRender, but it seems expensive.
2. Is there any other -proper- name, besides "cartoon"?

Example image from https://sites.tufts.edu/opioidpeptides/pathways-and-receptors/general-opioid-signaling/
[image]

Comment: You can draw them in Illustrator or any other vector graphics program.

Comment: You can use BioRender for free with slightly limited utility. I would call this an illustration or schematic.

Comment: they are called illustrations or diagrams and traditionally they are drawn by hand.